# Encryption between .NET and Iphone

Tags: .net, objective-c, encryption, aes

I am converting my .NET encryption code to Objective C.
Here is my code in .NET to create Key:

```
byte[] _corrpassword = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("1234567891123456");

PasswordDeriveBytes DerivedPassword = new PasswordDeriveBytes(_corrpassword, salt, "SHA1", _passwordIterations);
byte[] KeyBytes = DerivedPassword.GetBytes(_keySize / 8);
```

I am looking for equivelent of this into Objective C.

I tried creating this but both gives different results if I convert them to base64 string:

```
-(NSData *)AESKeyForPassword:(NSString *)password
           salt:(NSData *)salt
{
    NSMutableData * derivedKey = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:kCCKeySizeAES256];

    int result = CCKeyDerivationPBKDF(kCCPBKDF2,            // algorithm
                                    password.UTF8String,  // password
                                    password.length,  // passwordLength
                                    salt.bytes,           // salt
                                    salt.length,          // saltLen
                                    kCCPRFHmacAlgSHA1,    // PRF
                                    2,         // rounds
                                    derivedKey.mutableBytes, // derivedKey
                                    derivedKey.length); // derivedKeyLen

    NSAssert(result == kCCSuccess,
        @"Unable to create AES key for password: %d", result);

    return derivedKey;
}
```

If I compare `[derivedKey base64EncodingWithLineLength:0]` in objective C with `string passKey = Convert.ToBase64String(KeyBytes);` in .NET both gives different results.

EDIT: I tried in .NET side - `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` instead of `PasswordDeriveBytes` and the problem resolved. BUT, I can not change .NET code as it is already in production.

By my research what I understand is, `PasswordDeriveBytes` is using PBKDF1 and `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` and Objective C code using PBKDF2.

Please suggest what should I do?

Is there any option available in Objective C equivalent of `PasswordDeriveBytes`?

Comment: Tried all combinations but no results. Please help!!!

Comment: using this in .net   Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(_corrpassword, this._salt, _passwordIterations);
            byte[] KeyBytes = pdb.GetBytes(_keySize / 8);
            string passKey = Convert.ToBase64String(KeyBytes); gave me same results. But what is the difference?

Comment: The question is same but with no answer.

Comment: Still looking for a solution : Is there any option available in Objective C equivalent of PasswordDeriveBytes?

Comment: How big is `_keySize`? The maximum amount of bytes to get from `PasswordDeriveBytes` is 20 (the maximum size of PBKDF1 and SHA-1). If you request more than 20 bytes then `PasswordDeriveBytes` becomes proprietary, undocumented, non-deterministic, unsafe and just *wrong*.

Comment: Sorry, have to vote this as a dupe. Questions that have already been asked are deemed off topic, even if they don't have a direct answer yet. Note that implementing PBKDF1 is not as hard as implementing a primitive such as a hash method or symmetric cipher. The hash algorithms are already in place....

Comment: Thanks @owlstead. So I need to implement  PBKDF1 in objective C as I dont have option to change .NET side. We also have custom Java implementation of PBKDF1 which is compatible with .NET. It will be very helpful if you please give me some pointers where I can find the same in objective C. Thanks!